# Can I use a Bakelite MES Globe Holder to convert a lantern into a table lamp?

Tags: wiring

I want to turn a Moroccan **cast iron** lantern into a table lamp. Could I use a [Bakelite](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bakelite) MES globe holder to wire in a light globe?

Bakelight MES Globe Holder: [image]

Answer (score 1):

I would say *"eyup!"* This, however requires dealings with high voltage, high power electronics, so the first thing to look for is safety precautions. I have a boilerplate:

> Working with mains power should be performed according to your region's laws. It is dangerous and can seriously injure and kill you. Even the Earth wire may not be at 0V with respect to the objects around you due to its uncommon use as a return (or other more scary possibilities, like "That ain't the Earth wire, Jed! I just ran out of black!"). Please consult your local electrical codes before attempting to fiddle with it. Be careful using a cheap multimeter, as their maximum voltage ratings are sometimes inappropriately labeled CAT-II, III, and IV. I do not endorse messing with mains without [training](http://www.tableauellis.ca/tr.1d.2ch.1rt@-eng.jsp?&tid=51).

'Round where I live in Alberta, Canada, the Earth wire is green, and should be wired directly to the cast iron lamp. The hot (*not* green, gray, or white; often black or red) and neutral (gray or white) are connected to the two screws. [They should only be stripped/exposed enough to wrap around the screw once, and not over itself.](http://images.meredith.com/diy/images/2009/03/l_SCW_053_01.jpg) Ensure the Earth wire is connected to the Earth prong on the socket plug with a multimeter continuity test. Try it out! If a breaker trips, pat yourself on the back for connecting the Earth wire, as it may have just saved your life -- there is a short to the lamp, and power should be shut off and all connections checked with a multimeter.
<sup><sub>*The Earth wire connection is not required for operation -- just safety.*</sub></sup>

Comment: Note: You should **never** assume the wire colors are correct. My house is largely wired with orange and yellow wire, and the ground is carried through the flexible metal conduit through which all the wires run.

Answer (score 1):

MES (Miniature Edison Screw) lamp holders are designed for *low voltage* lamps and *not mains lamps*. You would need a SES (Small Edison Screw) or ES (standard Edison Screw) lamp holder to make this suitable for mains operation.

However, your question doesn't actually mention your intention to use mains voltage. If you want to use a low voltage lamp, you should be perfectly OK. Just don't use mains cable to wire to it otherwise someone will inevitably attach a mains plug to it one day with spectacular consequences.

I would also repeat tyblu's caveat about safety.